# LyX Hyphenation Not Working

Tags: xetex, lyx, luatex, babel, hyphenation

I need a little bit of help troubleshooting this. I'm also not too sure on what I can provide and how to provide it, but here's what I have:

LyX 2.1.2, with options in "Preferences>Language>Language package>Always Babel" and "Document Settings>Language>Language package>Always Babel"

I open up a new document of class "Article (Standard Class)". Preamble is empty. I just start typing "Maybe communication communication communication..." and when I render, I notice that the last "communication" of the first line is hanging over the paragraph.

I thought I remembered my documents ever being automatically hyphenated before accordingly, so I probably did something unknowingly and broke that functionality.

Adding `\usepackage[british]{babel}` or `\usepackage[american]{babel}` to the preamble has not helped regardless of whether I have the package in the options (mentioned earlier) turned on or off.

I have also tried adding `\hyphenpenalty=-1000` and `\exhyphenpenalty=-1000` to try to get it to break, but without success.

Please let me know if I need to provide more information and how.

Update: When I render using LuaTeX instead of XeTeX, the hyphenation works properly. I unfortunately don't know what does this indicate.

Update2: Here's the source as it appears in LyX View Source > Complete Source:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
maybe communication communication communication communication communication
communication communication communication communication communication
communication communication communication communication communication
communication communication communication
\end{document}
```

Update3: (refer to comments) The problem has been traced to having `Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for -1 languages loaded.` for XeTeX vs `Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 69 languages loaded.` for LuaTeX. As advised, I exported the source to a .tex file and used TexWorks to open it. Rendering with pdflatex or XeLaTeX (in the dropdown menu) causes the same problem, while selecting LuaLaTeX doesn't.

Since LuaTeX works, and visually appears the same (I'm using only English with the default Computer Modern font) I'll probably not try to troubleshoot this any further till I finish the assignment I'm on.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  the "default" english hyphenation is "com-mu-ni-ca-tion" so indeed it appears that somehow hyphenation is not turned on. the only other likely possibility is that you are somehow in a "boxed" environment that won't even break a line, but that doesn't seem to agree with your description.  can't help, really, only confirm what you already suspected.

Comment: Maybe if you export the `.tex` source, you'll be able to find the problem?

Comment: This hyphenates the fifth communication word as com-munication for me (copying LaTeX source from LyX): `\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
Maybe communication communication communication communication communication communication
\end{document}`

Comment: Check what's in your `View>Source` and `Document>LaTeX log`. Does babel report `Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for N languages loaded.`?

Comment: I see this: `Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for -1 languages loaded.` Is that the issue? View Source just shows me "maybe communication<x5>\n communication<x5>" and so on. EDIT: That message is when using pdflatex and XeTeX. When using LuaTeX, I get `Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 69 languages loaded.` Seems like we've found the problem.

Comment: Edit your question and add the LaTeX source of your example as in the comment of @PhilipPirrip.

Comment: You have to choose `Complete source` instead of `Current paragraph` in View Source pane. I guess `-1 languages loaded' means you have no hyphenation patterns installed.

Comment: Managed to put up the source. Thanks! Well, I don't think I don't have hyphenation patterns installed since it does load if I select LuaTeX, but strangely it doesn't with pdflatex and XeTeX (I edited the earlier comment in case you didn't notice).

Comment: The only thing that's different in your Update 2 from my example is that inputenc is missing. What do you get by saving my or your LaTeX code as a .tex file and pdflatex-ing it?

Comment: I get the same result as I did with LyX. (just to be sure I'm doing this correct: all I did was copy the source into a .tex file and double click on it. It opened with TeXworks which I then selected pdfLaTeX.)

Comment: Must be something wrong with the installation. Can't help any further, you'll have to wait for an expert in LaTeX distributions for Windows.  Might help if you do a complete update, reinstallation... I never liked how things work on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far! At least there's some progress, and I might be able to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just uninstall the whole MiKTeX package itself (don't touch LyX), [download from MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/download) then do a whole reconfigure from within LyX. It worked. Things are back to normal now.